# Minimizing convex sum of exponentials

Tags: calculus, optimization, convex-optimization

Let $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\geq0$ such that $ \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i = 1 $ and consider $u_1,\dots,u_n\in \mathbb{R}$.

I'm wondering if  there is any condition over $u_i$'s such that it is possible to find
$$\lambda_* = \arg\min_{\lambda} \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i e^{\lambda u_i}.$$

Any help or reference would be helpful!

**EDIT:** For example, if $u_i=i$ and $\alpha_i=1/n$ we can use the fact that this is a geometric sum and simplify the minimization expression to
$$\lambda_* = \arg\min_{\lambda} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n e^{\lambda i} =\arg\min_{\lambda} \frac{e^\lambda(e^{\lambda n}-1)}{n(e^\lambda-1)},$$
and I think it shouldn't be difficult to calculate in this case.

I'm searching for something like that. It would be super nice even for the case $u_i=i$ but for arbitrary $\alpha_i$'s.